# How to use AOP in JSTL?

Tags: java, spring, jstl, aop

I wanna AOP advisor in JSP file (Spring 3.0)

i.e..in JSP
My name is ${value.name}

I think that it might call value.getName() method..
So I set AOP like below...

```
@Around("execution(public java.lang.String a.b.c.*..get*())") 
public Object changeStr(ProceedingJoinPoint p) throws throwable 
{ 
 ... 
}
```

but it wasn't call...

How to use AOP in JSTL?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK expression languages (JSTL uses Java EL) use reflection, so IMHO the question should be: How to use AOP with reflection?. Here's an article on JBoss AOP and Reflection: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossaop/docs/2.0.0.GA/docs/aspect-framework/reference/en/html/reflection.html

Comment: Thomas // Sorry...I can't understand this article... :( How do I make Pointcut expression?

Comment: @JasonHong You basically have a point cut in your example. However, you can't add annotations to Java base classes, so you have to externally register that pointcut. How that is done depends on which framework you use, I assume it is Spring AOP. I don't really know Spring AOP, but you should be able to register point cuts through some XML declaration.